# How to indent a text and image that is left aligned in swift?

Tags: swiftui

I want to leave some space before the image and text in a button here is the code. SwiftUI
I also want to place the the contents close to the top of the page.

import SwiftUI

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
    
    
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Settings")
            .font(.title)
        
        Button(action: {
            print("Open feedback page")
        }) {
            HStack  {
                Image(systemName: "play.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title3)
                Text("Media player")
                    .font(.title3)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width:350, height: 70)
            .background(Color.red)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .padding()
        }
        
Spacer()
Spacer()
Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: try giving padding modifier to image, with leading and trailing .

Comment: thanks also could you help me to figure out how to use the wrapper for my database [link] (https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/515bbfc751dd97f5d0745dceee32d3b4) [link]

Comment: I can’t explain it without implementing it, but it looks like a database manager class with all required methods you need. You can add that in your code, as a separate framework and import it. Or directly as a file, and then play around with it.

Comment: which way will you advice for a rookie like me because I want to use it in my project and make reference to it

Comment: I would suggest you to use it as a framework, and import module in your classes.

Comment: alright thanks for your advice